# What would have happened if Mace Windu hadn't tried to kill Palpatine?

Tags: star-wars, darth-sidious

If instead of trying to kill Palpatine now uncovered as Darth Sidious in the Chancellors office he listens to Anakin about taking Sidious to the Senate to stand trial.

What would most likely have happened in that scenario?

Comment: You need to rephrase this question if you want to keep it open, something along the lines of "What is the process for trying a Chancellor after their arrest in the Galactic Republic?" Something that may have a canon answer and doesn't ask us to speculate on events.

Comment: We wouldn't have a long debate about if Han shot first...

Comment: I *am* the Senate!

Comment: Also possibly a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/84917/was-it-a-crime-in-the-republic-to-be-a-sith

Comment: Things would likely have been better, but not by much. Palpatine would probably still spin things so that the Jedi were to blame for their supposed coup. He certainly wouldn’t be punished (“He controls the Senate *and* the courts.”) Possibly Mace Windu would have been sentenced to death (and escaped, of course). Anakin wouldn’t have fallen to the Dark Side just then, but he probably would have in some time.

Comment: @Valorum i dont see how this is a duplicate of that

Comment: @Erchamion - Because the main plank of your question is whether Palpatine could have been taken to court. To court for what? All the Jedi have is a bunch of conjecture, rumour and hearsay about a mysterious figure called "Sidious" who's controlling everything. Literally the only thing that can pin on him objectively is that he's a secret Force user (e.g. by showing his midi-chlorian count) which isn't a crime.

Answer (score 2):

If Mace Windu had not attempted to kill Palpatine / Darth Sidious I fully expect Palpatine to have struck first.
Everything hinged on the successful execution of Order 66 for him, going along with being taken into custody would have revoked his power to activate it.

The only reason why he goaded Mace Windu into attacking was for Anakin's sake.